# jquery closest bug for same class

Tags: jquery, closest

ul alt2 should be aaa3 but becomes aaa0 why?

```js
$(" .item").each(function(e){
  tt=$(this);
  tt.attr("alt",e);
  $(this).closest('.item').attr('alt2', 'aaa'+$(this).attr('alt')  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='item' alt2=''>
  <li class='item'>aaaa</li>
  <li class='item'>aaaa</li>
  <li class='item'>aaaa</li>
</ul>
```

ul alt2 should be aaa3 but becomes aaa0 why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `e` is the index of the loop, since the `ul` is the first element of the selection `e` will be 0 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug in `.closest()`, but I suppose it could be *unintuitive*.  Look closely at the description in [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) (emphasis mine):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing ***the element itself*** and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

In this case *the element itself* is matching the selector:

```
$(this).closest('.item')
```

You could use `.parents` instead:

```
$(this).parents('.item')
```

Or use a more specific selector:

```
$(this).closest('ul.item')
```